# Derivation of Bessel recurrence relations from Series representation.

Tags: recurrence-relations, bessel-functions

I'm trying to get the recurrence relation
$$ J_{\nu-1}-J_{\nu+1}= \frac{2\nu}{x}J_\nu$$
using the series representation of the Bessel function of the first kind
$$ J_\nu = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k }{k!\Gamma(\nu+2k+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{\nu+2k}$$
but I am getting stuck at
$$J_{\nu-1}-J_{\nu+1} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k }{k!\Gamma(\nu+2k+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{\nu+2k}\left[\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{-1}(\nu+2k)-\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\frac{1}{\nu+2k+1}\right]$$
I know that there are other ways to get the recurrence relation, but it should be also possible to get it using this method, or am I wrong? Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: This method will work of course, but it helps to "align" the powers of $x$. Here you have a multiple of $x^{\nu+2k-1}$ next to a multiple of $x^{\nu+2k+1}$. It will help to re-index the terms of one sum in order to subtract, say two multiples of  $x^{\nu+2k-1}$.

Comment: If the steps I have made are right, than $\left[\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{-1}(\nu+2k)-\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\frac{1}{\nu+2k+1}\right] = \frac{2\nu}{x}$ which definitely is not true. This means that I've made an error somewhere, but I can't find it. I tried, to align the sums to, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: The point is that you haven't tried to align your sums. I don't have time to do it for you, but I suggest you ask yourself "what is the coefficient of $x^{\nu+2k-1}$ in $J_{\nu-1}(x)-J_{\nu+1}(x)$?"

Comment: You were right. I just stumbled accross the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just stumbled accross the answer of my question in a book about Special Functions. So [here's the step-by-step solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qwv5.png).